# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "в будущем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Продолжил инвестировать в недвижимость, чтобы впоследствии(,) в туманном будущем(,) быть финансово независимым...

Нуждается ли "в туманном будущем" в выделении запятыми в качестве уточнения?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, *"в туманном будущем"* — это именно уточнение: когда именно *"впоследствии"*. Соответственно, я бы запятые поставил.

Comment: Пояснение, а не уточнение. Уточнение ограничивает предыдущее слово, а не называет обозначенное им другими словами.

Comment: Вот оно и ограничивает: когда именно "впоследствии"? — "в туманном будущем" (не через день и не через год).

Comment: Может быть, может быть.